# code passenger_wsgi python

Tags: python, passenger, dreamhost

Can someone explain why this code shows a new version of Python on Dreamhost ?

```
import sys,os
# Force Passenger to run our virtualenv python
INTERP = "/home/site/env/bin/python"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ["Hello, world!" + sys.version]
```

While this code shows an old version :

```
#!/home/site/env/bin/python
import sys
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ["Hello, world!" + sys.version]
```

Comment: What versions do they return?

Comment: first script 1.2.3 and 2nd 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you throw some debugging code in `passenger_wsgi.py` to write out a log file:

```
x = open(os.path.expanduser('~/log.log'), 'w')
x.write(repr(sys.argv))
x.close()
```

and then examine `~/log.log`, then you’ll find that the python process that loads `passenger_wsgi.py` is started by running `/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/wsgi/request_handler.py`.

The first line of `/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/wsgi/request_handler.py` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and it loads `passenger_wsgi.py` by calling

```
app_module = imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', 'passenger_wsgi.py')
```

Since `passenger_wsgi.py` is loaded as a Python module, the `#!/home/site/env/bin/python` line at the start of your second `passenger_wsgi.py` file is treated simply as a Python comment and ignored. The default `/usr/bin/python` is used instead.

The recommended fix for this is exactly what your first `passenger_wsgi.py` does: `execl` the version of Python you actually want. I usually compile Python 2.7 in the shell user’s home directory and use that.

PS: If you’re curious I have [some notes about setting up Django on Dreamhost so that you can do continuous deployment](https://github.com/andrewdotn/deploy_polls)…

Comment: may i ask you some question through email on that site, I also have some problems with admin css.